# Promise Chain Stuck in a Loop

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise

I want to call a function that returns a promise twice, but when the function ends up calling itself forever, sometimes the outer one and sometimes the inner one. This is the problematic function where `retrieveDependency()` returns a Promise.

```
function renderDiffProject(projName, branchName, res, org=undefined){
   let newScan;
   let oldScan;
   retrieveDependency(projName, branchName, 1, org).then(result => { 
      newScan = result;
      console.log("inside retrieve deps");
      return retrieveDependency(projName, branchName, 2, org);
   })
   .then(result => {
      oldScan = result;
      console.log("successfully got dependencies")
      res.render('project', {projname: projName, branch: branchName, proj:JSON.stringify(newScan), oldproj:JSON.stringify(oldScan)})
   })
}
```

And this is the code for `retrieveDependency()`

```
function retrieveDependency(projname, branch, n, org=undefined){
   return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
      depList = []
      if (org != undefined){
         var sql = "SELECT (scanid) FROM foozie WHERE project = '" + projname + "' AND branch = '" + branch + "' AND org = '" + org + "' ORDER BY hist_id DESC LIMIT " + (n-1) + ",1"; 
      } else {
         var sql = "SELECT (scanid) FROM foozie WHERE project = '" + projname + "' AND branch = '" + branch + "' ORDER BY hist_id DESC LIMIT " + (n-1) + ",1";
      }
      return database.query(sql).then(result => {
         scan_id = result[0].scanid;
         var sql = "SELECT * FROM branch_scan WHERE fossa_scan_id = '" + scan_id + "'";
         return database.query(sql);
      }) 
      .then(result => {
         var promiseList = [];
         for (r in result){
            dep_name_version = result[r].dep_name_version;
            promiseList.push(getDepWrapper(dep_name_version, depList));
         }
         Promise.all(promiseList).then(result => {
            console.log("pushed all the promises for number", n);
            resolve(result);
         })
       })
   })
}
```

And `database.query` is defined as below:

```
class Database {
  constructor() {
      this.connection = mysql.createConnection({
        host: 'azure.com',
        user: 'admin-portal-mysql',
        password: '2341234#1',
        database: 'yatadb'
      });
  }
  query( sql, args ) {
      return new Promise( ( resolve, reject ) => {
          this.connection.query( sql, args, ( err, rows ) => {
              if ( err )
                  return reject( err );
              resolve( rows );
          } );
      } );
  }
```

Comment: You should really consider stopping with `new Promise()`. It's an anti pattern and bad practice. You might also benefit from `async/await` quite a bit. I can't tell right from the outside what could cause the inifite loop, but at least those 2 things should greatly simplify your code and might make it easier to see the problem.

Comment: Also noticed that you're mixing callbacks and promises in your database calls. Definitely worth cleaning that up too! If it helps I wrote this article: https://evertpot.com/executing-a-mysql-query-in-nodejs/

Comment: what is an anti pattern?

Comment: Best summed up as 'something that's not uncommon' but 'a pretty bad practice'. You can google 'Promise constructor anti-pattern' for plenty of information about specifically this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can simplify renderDiffProject using async/await:

```
async function renderDiffProject(projName, branchName, res, org=undefined){
    const newScan = await retrieveDependency(projName, branchName, 1, org);
    const oldScan = await retrieveDependency(projName, branchName, 2, org);
    console.log("successfully got dependencies")
    res.render('project', {projname: projName, branch: branchName, proj: JSON.stringify(newScan), oldproj: JSON.stringify(oldScan)})
}
```

We can also simplify retrieveDependency:

```
async function retrieveDependency(projname, branch, n, org=undefined) {
    // combine both queries
    const sql = `
        SELECT * FROM branch_scan 
        WHERE fossa_scan_id = (
            SELECT (scanid) FROM foozie 
            WHERE 
                project = ${projname} 
                AND branch = ${branch} 
                ${org ? `AND org = ${org}` : ``}
            ORDER BY hist_id DESC 
            LIMIT ${n - 1}, 1)`;

    const records = await database.query(sql);
    let dependencies = [];

    // map records to promises
    return await Promise.all(records.map(record => 
        getDepWrapper(record.dep_name_version, dependencies)
    ));
}
```

By simplifying your code it is easier to identify where you are making errors. Assuming that getDepWrapper actually resolves, you should be fine.